# Spring AWS SQS Reconnect After Losing Connection

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Cloud AWS (1.0.1.RELEASE) with Spring Boot to run a SQS consumer. The application runs fine, but when it looses network connection (for instance if I switch my WIFI off on my laptop when it runs on it), I see errors on the console and the application never recovers. It just hangs there and does not reconnect after the network becomes available. I have to kill it and bring it up. How do I force it to recover by itself?

```
// Spring Boot entry point: 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyConsumerConfiguration.class, args);
}

// Message Listener (A different class)
@MessageMapping(value = "myLogicalQueueName" )
public void receive(MyPOJO object) {

}
```

The error I see at console:

> Exception in thread "simpleMessageListenerContainer-1" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:473)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:297)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2422)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1130)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient$23.call(AmazonSQSAsyncClient.java:1678)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient$23.call(AmazonSQSAsyncClient.java:1676)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745

Comment: Hi Mohamed, do you mind sharing your project? I am struggling to get my Spring Boot app with Spring Cloud AWS to read from AWS SQS ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297688/spring-boot-spring-cloud-aws-and-aws-sqs-not-reading-from-the-queue ). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the problem why SQS is not able to reconnect after network connection lost.

Actually seems to be a problem in current Spring AWS implementation of `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java`

```
private class AsynchronousMessageListener implements Runnable {

    private final QueueAttributes queueAttributes;
    private final String logicalQueueName;

    private AsynchronousMessageListener(String logicalQueueName, QueueAttributes queueAttributes) {
        this.logicalQueueName = logicalQueueName;
        this.queueAttributes = queueAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning()) {
            ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = getAmazonSqs().receiveMessage(this.queueAttributes.getReceiveMessageRequest());
            CountDownLatch messageBatchLatch = new CountDownLatch(receiveMessageResult.getMessages().size());
            for (Message message : receiveMessageResult.getMessages()) {
                if (isRunning()) {
                    MessageExecutor messageExecutor = new MessageExecutor(this.logicalQueueName, message, this.queueAttributes);
                    getTaskExecutor().execute(new SignalExecutingRunnable(messageBatchLatch, messageExecutor));
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                messageBatchLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code spins up a new thread which does the polling to SQS queue to grab messages. Once network connection is dropped `getAmazonSqs().receiveMessage(this.queueAttributes.getReceiveMessageRequest())` throws `UnknownHostException`, which is not handled in the code and causes thread termination. 
So when network connection is established later on, there is no thread polling the queue to retrieve the data.

I have already raised a issue with Spring for this. Following is the link: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/82

Hope this explains it all.