# Spring Boot, Spring Cloud AWS and AWS SQS not reading from the queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sdk, spring-cloud

I am trying a to build a minimal gradle java project with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud AWS SQS but I can't get it to read from the queue.

These are my project files:

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
     imports {
          mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:1.1.0.RELEASE")
     }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.3.5.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:1.1.0.RELEASE")
    // if I don't add the line below, the annotation @MessageMapping is not found :(
    // I would have expected that cloud-starter-aws would have taken care of it
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:1.1.0.RELEASE")
    // this has been added to fix an exception happening, please read below
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.1.RELEASE")
}
```

Application.java:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

QueueListener.java:

```
package com.test.sqs;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import com.test.sqs.model.TestMessage;

public class QueueListener
{
    @MessageMapping("test_queue")
    private void receiveMessage(TestMessage testMessage)
    {
        System.out.println("Test message received: " + testMessage.getMessage());
    }
}
```

application.yaml in src/main/resources:

```
cloud:
    aws:
        credentials:
            accessKey: **********************
            secretKey: **********************
        region:
            static: us-west-2
```

The application throws an exception when starting (but you can see the exception just in log debug mode!):

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS credential profiles file not found in the given path: C:\src\collector\default
```

but always in the log I can see it did pick up my credentials from the yaml file:

```
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey' in [systemProperties]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey' in [systemEnvironment]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey' in [random]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey' in [applicationConfigurationProperties]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey' in [applicationConfigurationProperties] with type [String] and value '***'
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey' in [systemProperties]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey' in [systemEnvironment]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey' in [random]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey' in [applicationConfigurationProperties]
2016-05-19 11:15:14.546 DEBUG 11704 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey' in [applicationConfigurationProperties] with type [String] and value '***'
```

So I am not sure why it is looking somewhere else?

Also it's throwing this exception (always visible just if you are in logging debug mode):

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport
```

So I had to add in build.gradle

```
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.1.RELEASE")
```

But now the exception is not there anymore but the program starts and ends without doing anything, and it's not printing logs anymore!

Some other facts:

- the Application.java is in the right package to let the component scan to work, so Spring should see the QueueListener class,
- the application.yaml is read correctly, if a put a wrong region it complains,
- if I put wrong credentials (wrong accessKey or/and wrong secretKey) it does not complain, so I don't think it is trying to connect to AWS at all.

I am not sure if line 34 of build.gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:1.1.0.RELEASE")
// if I don't add the line below, the annotation @MessageMapping is not found :(
// I would have expected that cloud-starter-aws would have taken care of it
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:1.1.0.RELEASE")
// this has been added to fix an exception happening, please read below
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.1.RELEASE")
```

could be a symptom of the issue, I would expect for all the needed libraries to be loaded by the cloud-starter-aws automatically.

What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, and it was something stupid of course.

Spring was not loading the QueueListener class because it didn't have the Service / Component annotation, so:

```
@Service
public class SqsQueueSender
{
...
}
```

fixed the issue.