# Monitor connection to SQS and reconnect if it's lost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, listener, amazon-sqs

I have a Spring-Boot microservice which listens to Amazon SQS queue. Listener's configured as such:

```
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs.queue.name}", deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
public void queueListener(Message message) throws Exception {
    // some logic here
}
```

Everything works fine, but from time to time for the reason I can't understand (there are no exceptions or anything) my microservice just stops receiving messages. According to Amazon SQS console messages just start piling up in the queue and no one reads them.

If I redeploy the microservice all piled up messages are being processed in no time. And everything works fine for the time being, until this problem appears again.

My idea was to implement some cron-job which will monitor the connection to SQS. And if connection is lost (if it's the case in the first place) I'd reestablish it.

So is there a way to connect to SQS and start listening the queue not during application startup, but in runtime?

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.4.0. I also have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using aws-sdk for sqs? I would assume what you are suggesting is already implemented in the library, so instead of reinventing the wheel I'd investigate why this is not already happening.

Comment: I'm using `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` and `spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure` dependencies for sqs. Could you point to the class or method which does such a thing?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, mine is just an assumption. From a quick search it looks like you can configure somehow the `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory`, try to take a look at this maybe? https://gist.github.com/paulfairless/81eb87bd5a0e1b3a6d048ee913efc79a no idea if this will work, just throwing ideas :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762358/spring-aws-sqs-reconnect-after-losing-connection ?